# Tasks and lambda expressions syntax

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda, task-parallel-library

I am new to `Tasks` and still trying to grasp the concept.
While doing some research I came across [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C) article with the following line of code:

```
Task<int32> t = new Task<int32>(n => Sum((Int32)n), 1000);
```

From the example, I understand that `1000` is being passed as an argument to the `Sum` function, but I don't seem to understand the syntax.

My question is how does the compiler knows it should replace `n` with `1000` when Sum is called?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lambda's parameter is represented in the lambda as `n` before the `=>`. That `n` is then passed as an argument to the `Sum()` method that is called within the body of the lambda expression.

If I rewrite the lambda expression as a delegate, it might be clearer to you:

```
Task<Int32> t = new Task<Int32>(
    delegate(Int32 n) { return Sum((Int32)n); }, 
    1000);
```

It isn't replaced at compile-time but at runtime, once the `Task` is executed.

Comment: Thanks, My mistake was I missed the overload of `Task(Func<object, TResult> function, object state);`